# Gradle's mustRunAfter/finalizedBy only for a specific task?

Tags: gradle

I'm trying to get Gradle's `mustRunAfter` and `finalizedBy` to work only for a specific task. Take this example `build.gradle`:

```
task removeTestDatabaseContainer {
  doLast {
    println '\ninside removeTestDatabaseContainer\n'
  }
}

task startTestDatabaseContainer {
  doLast {
    println '\ninside startTestDatabaseContainer\n'
  }
  finalizedBy removeTestDatabaseContainer
}

task flywayMigrate { t->
  doLast {
    println '\n inside flywayMigrate\n'
  }
}

task flywayClean { t->
  doLast {
    println '\n inside flywayClean\n'
  }
}

task testEverything {
    dependsOn startTestDatabaseContainer
    dependsOn flywayMigrate
    dependsOn flywayClean

    flywayMigrate.mustRunAfter startTestDatabaseContainer
    flywayMigrate.finalizedBy flywayClean

    flywayClean.mustRunAfter flywayMigrate
    flywayClean.finalizedBy removeTestDatabaseContainer
}
```

I'm happy with how `testEverything` works. I want the output I'm getting from that task:

```
➜  gradle testEverything
Parallel execution is an incubating feature.
:startTestDatabaseContainer

inside startTestDatabaseContainer

:flywayMigrate

 inside flywayMigrate

:flywayClean

 inside flywayClean

:removeTestDatabaseContainer

inside removeTestDatabaseContainer

:testEverything

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 0.597 secs
```

However, when I run only `flywayMigrate` I get unexpected problems. This is the output:

```
➜  gradle flywayMigrate                
Parallel execution is an incubating feature.
:flywayMigrate

 inside flywayMigrate

:flywayClean

 inside flywayClean

:removeTestDatabaseContainer

inside removeTestDatabaseContainer


BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 0.605 secs
```

This is not the output I want. I would like only `flywayMigrate` to run. **Question 1)** How can I make `testEverything` work as it does and at the same time have `gradle flywayMigrate` invoke only the `flywayMigrate`-task?

**Question 2)**
I'm told this has something to do with the fact that everything inside the brackets of `task testEverything {}` is configuration, which is always processed by Gradle. So any `mustRunAfter`/`finalizedBy` I set within a task will have "global effect". But in that case, why doesn't `gradle flywayMigrate` invoke `startTestDatabaseContainer`? (Because of the line `flywayMigrate.mustRunAfter startTestDatabaseContainer` inside the `testEverything` task.)

Edit: I was directed to [Ordering tasks](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#sec:ordering_tasks) and [Finalizer tasks](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#sec:finalizer_tasks) in the Gradle documentation and they answer question 2: `mustRunAfter` only takes effect when both tasks are ran. `finalizedBy` on the other hand takes effect when only the task it is set on is ran. That answers why `flywayClean` and `removeTestDatabasContainer` are ran when I execute `gradle flywayMigrate`.

I'm still struggling to make `gradle testEverything` work as it does above and at the same time get `gradle flywayMigrate` to just execute `flywayMigrate`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to the help of eskatos on #gradle on Freenode I found a solution. It was simply to remove the finalizedBy-lines i had. Updated build.gradle that works:

```
task removeTestDatabaseContainer {
  doLast {
    println '\ninside removeTestDatabaseContainer\n'
  }
}

task startTestDatabaseContainer {
  doLast {
    println '\ninside startTestDatabaseContainer\n'
  }
  finalizedBy removeTestDatabaseContainer
}

task flywayMigrate { t->
  doLast {
    println '\n inside flywayMigrate\n'
  }
}

task flywayClean { t->
  doLast {
    println '\n inside flywayClean\n'
  }
}

task testEverything {
    dependsOn startTestDatabaseContainer
    dependsOn flywayMigrate
    dependsOn flywayClean

    flywayMigrate.mustRunAfter startTestDatabaseContainer
    //flywayMigrate.finalizedBy flywayClean

    flywayClean.mustRunAfter flywayMigrate
    //flywayClean.finalizedBy removeTestDatabaseContainer
}
```